# Aligning three columns of equations

Tags: align

I am trying to create a list like below, [image]

but I can't seem to to align the three columns of equations and when I do I get something like

[image]

Here is my code:

```
$\begin{array}{ccc}
x_8 = 93 \quad y_8 = 64 \quad z_8 = 61\\
x_7 = 186 \quad y_7 = 32 \quad z_7 = 61\\
x_6 = 231 \quad y_6 = 32 \quad z_6 = 29
\end{array}$
```

Added image:

[image]

How would I align the two tables like that?

Comment: `align(*)` supports multiple alignment points. Here is the syntax for the first line: ``x_8 &=93 & y_8 &= 64 & z_8=61 \\``, then just repeat (of course assumes the `amsmath` package)

Comment: @daleif How do I manage the spacing? What if I want the spacing to look like as in the first picture I have?

Comment: Then lookup `alignat` though it has a slightly different syntax

Answer (score 11):

Here are 3 solutions. The second solution uses the `matrix*` environment from `mathtools`. It allows for an optional argument `l,c` or `l`. The default is `c`. The last solution relies on `alignat`, and gives an easy control on the spacing of the columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[ \begin{array}{lll}%
x_8 = 93  &  y_8 = 64  &  z_8 = 61\\
x_7 = 186  &  y_7 = 32 &  z_7 = 61\\
x_6 = 231  &  y_6 = 32  &  z_6 = 29
\end{array}\]%

\[ \begin{matrix*}[l]%
x_8 = 93  &  y_8 = 64  &  z_8 = 61\\
x_7 = 186  &  y_7 = 32 &  z_7 = 61\\
x_6 = 231  &  y_6 = 32  &  z_6 = 29
\end{matrix*}\]%

\begin{alignat*}{3}
x_8  & = 93  &\qquad  y_8 &  = 64  &\qquad  z_8  & = 61\\
x_7  & = 186  &  y_7 & = 32 &  z_7  & = 61\\
x_6  & = 231  &  y_6  & = 32  &  z_6  & = 29
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're forgetting the simplest one, that is `align*`

Comment: You don't have control on the spacing between groups, that's why I didn't propose it. But I'll mention it.

Comment: How do I do the last image I added in my question?

Comment: You're insatiable :o) There seems to be to groups of 3, or is it one group of 6?

Comment: There are two groups.

Answer (score 10):

Two additional solutions:

- a pure `align*` environment, and
- an `array` environment with automatic insertion of the `=` symbols

Note that the `array`-based solution permits typesetting the numbers *after* the `=` symbols in right-aligned rather than in left-aligned mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' environment
\usepackage{array}   % for '\newcolumntype' directive
\newcolumntype{R}{r@{{}={}}r} % for the array-based solution
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
x_8 &= 93  & y_8 &= 64 & z_8 &= 61\\
x_7 &= 186 & y_7 &= 32 & z_7 &= 61\\
x_6 &= 231 & y_6 &= 32 & z_6 &= 29
\end{align*}

\[
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.33}
\begin{array}{ R @{\qquad} R @{\qquad} R }
x_8 &  93 & y_8 & 64 & z_8 & 61\\
x_7 & 186 & y_7 & 32 & z_7 & 61\\
x_6 & 231 & y_6 & 32 & z_6 & 29
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

This might seem overkill. `;-)` Look at the (forthcoming) proceedings of the GuITMeeting 2016 (to be held at the end of October) for comments over the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\providecommand\fpeval{\fp_eval:n}

\NewDocumentCommand{\nforeach}{ m +m }
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l__manual_nforeach_type_tl
  \keys_set:nn { manual/nforeach }
   {
    type=integers,start = 1, step = 1, end = 0,
   }
  \keys_set:nn { manual/nforeach } { #1 }
  \__manual_nforeach_exec:n { #2 }
 }

\int_new:N \g__manual_foreach_map_int
\int_new:N \g__manual_fp_map_int
\tl_new:N \l__manual_nforeach_type_tl

\keys_define:nn { manual/nforeach }
 {
  type .choice:,
  type .value_required:n = true,
  type/integers .code:n = \tl_set:Nn \l__manual_nforeach_type_tl { integers },
  type/fp       .code:n = \tl_set:Nn \l__manual_nforeach_type_tl { fp },
  type/alph     .code:n = \tl_set:Nn \l__manual_nforeach_type_tl { alph },
  type/Alph     .code:n = \tl_set:Nn \l__manual_nforeach_type_tl { Alph },
  start .tl_set:N = \l__manual_nforeach_start_tl,
  step  .tl_set:N = \l__manual_nforeach_step_tl,
  end   .tl_set:N = \l__manual_nforeach_end_tl,
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__manual_nforeach_exec:n
 {
  \int_gincr:N \g__manual_foreach_map_int
  \str_case:Vn \l__manual_nforeach_type_tl
   {
    {integers}{\__manual_nforeach_exec_integers:n { #1 }}
    {fp}      {\__manual_nforeach_exec_fp:n { #1 }}
    {alph}    {\__manual_nforeach_exec_alph:Nn \int_to_alph:n { #1 }}
    {Alph}    {\__manual_nforeach_exec_alph:Nn \int_to_Alph:n { #1 }}
   }
  \int_gdecr:N \g__manual_foreach_map_int
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nn { V }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__manual_nforeach_exec_integers:n
 {
  \int_step_inline:nnnn
   { \l__manual_nforeach_start_tl }
   { \l__manual_nforeach_step_tl }
   { \l__manual_nforeach_end_tl }
   { #1 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__manual_nforeach_exec_alph:Nn
 {
  \cs_set:cn { __manual_nforeach_alph_ \int_use:N \g__manual_foreach_map_int :n } { #2 }
  \cs_generate_variant:cn
   { __manual_nforeach_alph_ \int_use:N \g__manual_foreach_map_int :n }
   { f }
  \int_step_inline:nnnn
   { \int_from_alph:f { \l__manual_nforeach_start_tl } }
   { \l__manual_nforeach_step_tl }
   { \int_from_alph:f { \l__manual_nforeach_end_tl } }
   {
    \use:c { __manual_nforeach_alph_ \int_use:N \g__manual_foreach_map_int :f }
     { #1 { ##1 } }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cs_generate_variant:Nn { c }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \int_from_alph:n { f }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__manual_nforeach_exec_fp:n
 {
  \manual_fp_step_inline:nnnn
   { \l__manual_nforeach_start_tl }
   { \l__manual_nforeach_step_tl }
   { \l__manual_nforeach_end_tl }
   { #1 }
 }

% a replacement for \fp_step_inline:nnnn
\seq_new:N \l__manual_fp_step_seq
\fp_new:N \l__manual_fp_step_start_fp

\cs_new_protected:Nn \manual_fp_step_inline:nnnn
 {
  \int_gincr:N \g__manual_fp_map_int
  \seq_clear_new:c { l__manual_fp_step_ \int_use:N \g__manual_fp_map_int _seq }
  \fp_compare:nTF { #2 < \c_zero_fp }
   {
    \__manual_fp_step_make_neg:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
   }
   {
    \__manual_fp_step_make_pos:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
   }
  \seq_map_inline:cn { l__manual_fp_step_ \int_use:N \g__manual_fp_map_int _seq } { #4 }
  \int_gdecr:N \g__manual_fp_map_int
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__manual_fp_step_make_neg:nnn
 {
  \fp_set:Nn \l__manual_fp_step_start_fp { #1 }
  \fp_do_while:nn { \l__manual_fp_step_start_fp >= #3 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:cx { l__manual_fp_step_ \int_use:N \g__manual_fp_map_int _seq }
     { \fp_eval:n { \l__manual_fp_step_start_fp } }
    \fp_add:Nn \l__manual_fp_step_start_fp { #2 }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__manual_fp_step_make_pos:nnn
 {
  \fp_set:Nn \l__manual_fp_step_start_fp { #1 }
  \fp_do_while:nn { \l__manual_fp_step_start_fp <= #3 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:cx { l__manual_fp_step_ \int_use:N \g__manual_fp_map_int _seq }
     { \fp_eval:n { \l__manual_fp_step_start_fp } }
    \fp_add:Nn \l__manual_fp_step_start_fp { #2 }
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\lforeach}{ s O{} m +m }
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \manual_lforeach:non { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
   }
   {
    \manual_lforeach:nnn { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \manual_lforeach:nnn
 {
  \keys_set:nn { manual/lforeach } { single }
  \keys_set:nn { manual/lforeach } { #1 }
  \clist_set:Nn \l__manual_lforeach_list_clist { #2 }
  \int_gincr:N \g__manual_foreach_map_int
  \__manual_lforeach_define:n { #3 }
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l__manual_lforeach_list_clist
   {
    \use:c { __manual_lforeach_ \int_use:N \g__manual_foreach_map_int _action:w } ##1 \q_stop
   }
  \int_gdecr:N \g__manual_foreach_map_int
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \manual_lforeach:nnn { no }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__manual_lforeach_define:n
 {
  \exp_last_unbraced:NcV
   \cs_set:Npn
   { __manual_lforeach_ \int_use:N \g__manual_foreach_map_int _action:w }
   \l__manual_lforeach_format_tl
   \q_stop
   {#1}
 }

\keys_define:nn { manual/lforeach }
 {
  format .tl_set:N = \l__manual_lforeach_format_tl,
  single .code:n = \tl_set:Nn \l__manual_lforeach_format_tl { ##1 },
  double .code:n = \tl_set:Nn \l__manual_lforeach_format_tl { ##1/##2 },
  triple .code:n = \tl_set:Nn \l__manual_lforeach_format_tl { ##1/##2/##3 },
 }

%%% for this application
\NewDocumentCommand{\newlist}{m}
 {
  \seq_clear_new:c { l_manual_list_#1_seq }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\addtolist}{mm}
 {
  \seq_put_right:cn { l_manual_list_#1_seq } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\uselist}{mm}
 {
  \seq_use:cn { l_manual_list_#1_seq } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\showlist}{m}
 {
  \seq_show:c { l_manual_list_#1_seq }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newlist{listA}\newlist{listB}

\begin{document}

\[
% first table
\lforeach[format=#1/#2/#3/#4,]{
  8/93/64/61,
  7/186/32/61,
  6/231/32/29,
  5/462/16/29,
  4/483/16/13,
  3/966/8/13,
  2/975/8/5,
  1/1950/4/5,
  0/1953/4/1,
}{\addtolist{listA}{x_{#1}=#2 & y_{#1}=#3 & z_{#1}=#4 \\}}
% second table
\nforeach{start=5,step=-1,end=0}{%
  \addtolist{listB}{
    x_{#1}=\fpeval{65*2^(5-#1)} &
    y_{#1}=\fpeval{2^(#1+2)}  &
    z_{#1}=1 \\
  }%
}
\begin{array}[t]{lll}
\uselist{listA}{}
\end{array}
\qquad
\begin{array}[t]{lll}
\uselist{listB}{}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Of course, the left-hand table can also be typeset by

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
\def\row#1/#2/#3/#4,{%
  x_{#1}=#2 & y_{#1}=#3 & z_{#1}=#4 \\
}
\begin{array}{lll}
\row 8/93/64/61,
\row 7/186/32/61,
\row 6/231/32/29,
\row 5/462/16/29,
\row 4/483/16/13,
\row 3/966/8/13,
\row 2/975/8/5,
\row 1/1950/4/5,
\row 0/1953/4/1,
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

but it's no fun. `;-)`

Comment: This is what dark side of LaTeX looks like :)